# What type of drywall texture is this and how do i create it?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

Repairing a crack in a garage wall and need to re-create the texture shown. Appreciate any help as Google was stumped.[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a *Tree bark texture* which is created with a drywall roller cover.

You might be able to find one of these covers at the big box hardware stores, if not, you can source them from similar [online stores](https://a.co/d/i8tPvQq).

*Image credit: Amazon*
[image: treebark texture roller cover]

Comment: Thank you! I also found the video below which is an alternate way to create that pattern.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBlph6um9aY

Comment: I think the follow-up question should be "How you you make a the new tree-bark match the original?"

Comment: @RonJohn easy - you tear it all off and redo an entire wall with the same roller.   Might have to do the entire room.  Or you buy a tall piece of furniture to hide the repair :)